# Dynamic cache angular 4 not working PWA

Tags: angular, caching, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am working on a progressive web app in angular 4 which seems to be working fine in online mode. It does work on offline mode as well unless I involve dynamic caching.

So there is this `ngsw-manifest.json` in which I have done some configuration:

```
{
    "routing": {
        "index": "/index.html",
        "routes": {
            "/": {
                "match": "exact"
            },
            "/coffee": {
                "match": "prefix"
            }
        }
    },
    "static.ignore": [
        "^\/icons\/.*$"
    ],
    "external": {
        "urls": [
            {
                "url": "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
            },
            {
                "url": "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v29/2fcrYFNaTjcS6g4U3t-Y5ZjZjT5FdEJ140U2DJYC3mY.woff2"
            }
        ]
    },
    "dynamic": {
        "group": [
            {
                "name": "api",
                "urls": {
                    "http://localhost:3000/coffees": {
                        "match": "prefix"
                    }
                },
                "cache": {
                    "optimizeFor": "freshness",
                    "networkTimeoutMs": 1000,
                    "maxEntries": 30,
                    "strategy": "lru",
                    "maxAgeMs": 360000000
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So the `dynamic` key in the above json caches the content on the page for offline use. 
Here is an image of the content being cached:

[image]

However when I try to reload the page in offline mode after caching, the content is not being shown. Is there some configuration that I missed?

Comment: Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-progressive-web-app-architectures#key_concepts), the app shell approach relies on caching the `shell` of your web application using a service worker. Using the app shell + dynamic content model greatly improves app performance and works really well with service worker caching as a progressive enhancement. However, when service workers are not supported in your browser, the assets are not cached offline but the content is still fetched over the network and the user still gets a basic experience.

Comment: I am also waiting for dynamic cache getting fixed. https://github.com/angular/mobile-toolkit/issues/168

Comment: Hey @bob. were you able to find some solution to that?

Answer (score 1):

While waiting for `ngsw` to be ready, you could use [`workbox-build`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/workbox-build) npm package in your Angular project.

For precaching assets:

```
const workbox: WorkboxBuild = require('workbox-build');
workbox.injectManifest({
  globDirectory: './dist/',
  globPatterns: ['**\/*.{html,js,css,png,jpg,json}'],
  globIgnores: ['build/*', 'sw-default.js', 'workbox-sw.js','assets/icons/**/*'],
  swSrc: './src/sw-template.js',
  swDest: './dist/sw-default.js',
});
```

For dynamic caching:

```
const workboxSW = new self.WorkboxSW();

// work-images-cache
workboxSW.router.registerRoute('https://storage.googleapis.com/xxx.appspot.com/(.*)',
  workboxSW.strategies.cacheFirst({
    cacheName: 'work-images-cache',
    cacheExpiration: {
      maxEntries: 60
    },
    cacheableResponse: { statuses: [0, 200] }
  })
);
```

You could cache web fonts etc. by calling another `registerRoute`. Realistic usage example [here](https://github.com/bob-lee/ng-joanne-lee).

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced the same issue when I used the same configuration.
Below worked out for me and I was able to retrieve list of coffees from the cache in offline mode
Use `dataGroups` for dynamic caching in `ngsw-config.json` as shown below

```
    "dataGroups":[
      {
       "name":"api",
       "urls":[
        "/coffees"
       ],
      "cacheConfig": {
       "strategy": "performance",
       "timeout": "10s",
       "maxSize": 30,
       "maxAge": "1d"
       }
     }
   ]
```

Below articles can be helpful:

- [Angular service worker part-1](https://medium.com/progressive-web-apps/a-new-angular-service-worker-creating-automatic-progressive-web-apps-part-1-theory-37d7d7647cc7)
- [Angular service worker part-2](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/a-new-angular-service-worker-creating-automatic-progressive-web-apps-part-2-practice-3221471269a1)